# How to get the Log Directory in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, logging, directory

I see the ability to get the path to the ApplicationsSupport Directory using Swift.

Is there an interface to get the Log directory?

Comment: What platform?  iOS?  OS X?  We need more information and your attempt at solving your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no Apple-provided way to get this. This seems odd at first glance, but I believe Apple's rationale is that we are actually not supposed to need to directly access this directory, and instead should use [their logging API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) which takes care of these details.

However, I'm using SwiftyBeaver to write logs to a file, and used the following code to generate the logs directory URL:

```swift
let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
let logsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    .appendingPathComponent("Logs", isDirectory: true)
    .appendingPathComponent(bundleID, isDirectory: true)
```